# Linking Pulse buttons and make tables disappear

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am having trouble linking my pulse buttons to their corresponding table, my code is attached can anyone give some feed back on how to make only one table show at a time based on a click on the pulse button?

https://codepen.io/jmrowe0231/pen/KGVYLp

```
label div.pulse-button {
  position:relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(232, 76, 61, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00aed6;
  background-image: url(http://image.carnivalcruiselineemail.com/lib/fe9513727761047c7c/m/10/plus_icon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -ms-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
}

label[for=Mexico1] div.pulse-button {
  left: -143px;
  top: -175px;
}

label[for=Mexico2] div.pulse-button {
  left: 280px;
  top: -192px;
}

label[for=Mexico3] div.pulse-button {
  left: -243px;
  top: -278px;
}

 @ -webkit-keyframes pulse {
 to {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
}
}
 @-moz-keyframes pulse {
 to {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
}
}
 @-ms-keyframes pulse {
 to {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
}
}
 @keyframes pulse {
 to {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(232, 76, 61, 0);
}
```

Comment: This would probably be a good case for some javascript click events.

Comment: I am using in an email, java script is not supported. Need to accomplish this using html and css

Comment: well you could do something potential using hidden check boxes and write styles against the `:checked` pseudo selector to show the correct table.